# Error with SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, sql

C#, Razor

my code is:

```
@using (SqlConnection Praktikum2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mark\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Connection;Integrated Security=True"))
{

using(connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name = " + Request.Params["kategory"]);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();  //ERROR!!!
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string ID = reader["KategorieID"].ToString() ;

        Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}", ID);
    }
    reader.Close();
};
}
```

i get an error that there's a wrong syntax near "=".

how can i solve this?

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation and your problem disappears

Comment: You should definitely be using SQL parameters for your command.  Using this method will be slower and also leave you open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

If your kategory column is not of integer data type then you need to surround your value with (') i.e single quote characters

Then your query will be like

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name ='" + Request.Params["kategory"] + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the `connection` to the `command`. So when you call `ExecuteReader()`, it does not know on which connection it should be executed.

You can assign the connection like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name = " + Request.Params["kategory"],
          connection); // provide connection as second parameter!
```

or use `connection.CreateCommand()` to create your command.

Second, you forgot the quotation marks around your string:

```
      "SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name = '" + Request.Params["kategory"] + "'"
```

but **inserting user data directly into your query opens your code to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)**. Please use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: @Jamiec right, missed that error description. Obviously `ExecuteReader` first parses the SQL and then checks the connection. So after fixing the quotation marks/paramterizing the missing connection would have been the next error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the missing quotes around the value passed for your search. You could add a set of single quote before and after the value obtained by the Request but that would be a bigger error and the source of a problem called Sql Injection.

The only way to handle this is to use a parameter query

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory 
                                      WHERE Name = @name", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request.Params["kategory"];
```

Also, as noted in another answer, your code seems to not have associated the connection to the command, I think that it is just a typo here because the error message in that case would be 'need an open connection'

Comment: A parameter has a type. The Sql Server client defines various types. NVarChar means that you are passing a value that is stored in a column of type NVarChar in your database table. This removes any kind of ambiguity between the NET code and the Database Engine.

Comment: These types are defined by the [SqlDbType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx). Of course you could adjust the type according to the  actual database type of your column.

Comment: Do you have _using System.Data;_ at the beginning of your source code?

Comment: i used @using System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: You need also System.Data

Comment: still getting an error "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: the 
Parameterized query '(@name nvarchar(4000))SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name' expects the @name-Parameter, Which is not provided"

Answer (score 1):

The exception is caused by how you are creating your sql statement. The fix should not be correcting the syntax but using parameters instead. This will prevent sql injection attacks.

Also

1. You really should not be writting sql in your views, do it in your controller method instead and return the result in the Model to be used in your view. Better yet, abstract it to a different layer and call that layer from your controller. This has to do with SoS (Separation of Concerns), your code will very difficult to maintain if you just write everything into your views.
2. Wrap your connections, commands, and readers in `using` blocks.

Modified Code

```
@{
    using(SqlConnection Praktikum2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mark\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Connection;Integrated Security=True"))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT KategoryID FROM Kategory WHERE Name = @name", Praktikum2))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar){ Value = Request.Params["kategory"]});
        connection.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string ID = reader["KategorieID"].ToString() ;
                Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}", ID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```